# How to use auto increment value in mysql CONCAT function?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have that problem:

I want to insert new row in image table like this:

```
INSERT INTO image (pr_id, kelias, tipas) VALUES(111111, CONCAT('1111111111', '_', image.id, '.jpg'), '0')
```

but I do something wrong with `CONCAT` function when I try to input `image.id` value ir return 0 every time.

`image.id` is auto increment.

Comment: So you want to use the id of the row you're trying to insert so you can prepend it to the image name?

Comment: Erm, why? You are duplicating the data you can easily extrapolate at any point. Also, like Devart posted - you deal with this type of problem via triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BEFORE INSERT trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON image
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.kelias = CONCAT(NEW.kelias, NEW.pr_id);
END
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the question; auto_increment column gives value 0 ie `New.id`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INSERT INTO image (pr_id, kelias, tipas)
SELECT 11111, 
       CONCAT('1111111111', '_', max(image.id) + 1, '.jpg'), 
       '0'
FROM image
```

Comment: Your solution is inaccurate, you cannot assume that the next ID that's auto_incremented is incremented by 1, or that the max ID won't change mid-way trough query, giving you effectively wrong results. Better solution is using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO image (kelias, tipas) VALUES('anything', '0')");
$img_id = mysql_insert_id();
$kelias = '1111111111' . '_' . $img_id . '.jpg';
mysql_query("UPDATE image SET kelias='$kelias' WHERE pr_id = $img_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BEFORE INSERT trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON image
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.kelias = CONCAT( NEW.kelias , '_', 

  (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "<your database name here>"
  AND TABLE_NAME = "image" )

  , '.jpg');
END
```

And then get the desired result by :

```
INSERT INTO image (pr_id, kelias, tipas) VALUES(111111, '1111111111', '0')
```